# Error reading/formatting datetime field in SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime

I am doing a java application that reads an SQL Server table using the Debezium connector for Kafka.

I have successfully read the fields of type Datetime but I am having trouble reading the fields of type Datetime2.

Basically what it does is to receive a String parameter with the value that Debezium returns and a parameter that indicates the format in which I want the date to be returned.

Examples:

Datetime field (works) return "01-27-2020 01:13:19 PM":

`value = "1580127199787"
dataFormatPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH: mm: ss"`

Field datetime2 (does not work) "01-02-2030 13:13:19" but return "50091978-09-11T02:00:00":

`value = "1580688000000000000"
dataFormatPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH: mm: ss"`

```
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Time;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class DatetimeFormatter implements Formatter {

public String getFormattedValue(String value,String dataFormatPattern) {

    final Date dateDecoded;

    Long dataEncoded =Long.parseLong(value);

    dateDecoded = Timestamp.toLogical(Timestamp.SCHEMA,dataEncoded);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dataFormatPattern);

    String strDate= formatter.format(dateDecoded);

    return strDate;
}
}
```

Comment: So is it correct that Debezium returns your `1580688000000000000` while in DB it stores as `01-02-2030 13:13:19`?

Comment: Why are you using SimpleDateFormat rather than DateTimeFormatter? Looks like you need more unit tests for your method

Comment: The problem is in the line before SimpleDateFormat. dataDecoded does not have the correct date because Timestamp.toLogical does not return the value that i expect